# Having a dynamic number of standalone views divide the space evenly

Tags: eclipse-rcp

When showing multiple instances of the same view, I would like the following to hold true:

- The views do not stack
- The number of them is dynamic (let's say 1 to 10) and not known initially: they are added by the user, one by one
- They are positioned above/below each other
- They take up all the vertical space amongst themselves
- By default they have equal height (if there are 3 views, each gets 1/3 of the total vertical space, adding a 4th view causes them all to get 1/4 etc)

What I use to add the views in Perspective is the following:

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
  String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();
  layout.addStandaloneViewPlaceholder(MarkerView.VIEW_ID + ":0", IPageLayout.TOP, 0.6F, editorArea, true);
  layout.addStandaloneViewPlaceholder(MarkerView.VIEW_ID + ":1", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.6F, editorArea, true);
  layout.addStandaloneViewPlaceholder(MarkerView.VIEW_ID + ":2", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.6F, editorArea, true);
```

The problem is that not knowing what the number of views will be, the ratios won't provide equal space to all instances of the view.

Is it somehow possible to adjust the ratios of existing views after adding a new one?

I've also tried having the view class implement ISizeProvider (which I admit I do not have a full grasp of), but haven't managed to achieve what I want with that either:

```
@Override
public int getSizeFlags(boolean width) {
  return width ? 0 : SWT.FILL | SWT.MIN | SWT.MAX;
}

@Override
public int computePreferredSize(boolean width, int availableParallel, int availablePerpendicular, int preferredResult) {
  int windowHeight = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getActiveShell().getBounds().height;
  int nrOfViews = Model.getInstance().markerCounter;
  return width ? preferredResult : windowHeight / nrOfViews;
}
```

Is this approach something in the right direction at least?